# Why is my element null?

Tags: javascript, null, getelementbyid

Why when I do an `alert` of the value (see below) it returns `null`? When an element with that ID exists?

```
// make reference to divs
var countdown_timer = document.getElementById("countdown_timer");
var countdown_image = document.getElementById("countdown_image");

// For element manipulation

if (type == 'image') {
    var element = countdown_image;
} else if (type == 'timer') {
    var element = countdown_timer;
}

alert(countdown_timer);
```

The div is as below..

```
<div class="timer" id="countdown_timer"></div>
```

Comment: Make sure that you call `document.getElementById` *after* the concerning element has been parsed and inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the javascript is being executed before the elements on your page are not loaded, thus the selector isn't finding anything.  Is your javascript above the `<body>` tag?  Try putting it after `</body>` and see how that works for you.

Another solution is to do:

```
window.onload = function () {
//put all your JS here
}
```

Comment: Yeah..... I was calling the javascript in the page, in the body section, but above the elements..... moved it below them & it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
onload = function() {
 // put you code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `document.getElementById` needs to be after the markup for the div.

```
<div class="timer" id="countdown_timer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var countdown_timer = document.getElementById("countdown_timer");
 ...
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could use the window.onload event, which would be the better way to go.

Comment: Yep.... I fixed it up liked that just before I seen your answer going by the other answers haha :)